# Custom datatable sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table of data that is order by rank which can be entered through an input box.

The rank is a single digit number 1 through 9 or it could be blank. I want the blanks to always appear at the end of the list whenever I sort.

See the JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/afEHc/

If I use:

```
"aoColumns": [ { "sSortDataType": "dom-text" }, null ]
```

It works picks up the new values but the order is incorrect. That is the blanks need to always appear at the end.

If I use:

```
"aoColumns": [{"sType": "data-rank"}, null ]
```

It works correct initially but then breaks when either I sort by another column first or add a value to the rank column.

Any point or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unfortunetely you cannot have a `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnSortData['data-rank']`, at least what I know of.

But you can use the `dom-text` as you have tried, and set the `sType` to be `data-rank` :

```
"aoColumns": [
   { "sSortDataType": "dom-text", "sType": "data-rank" },
    null
]
```

new custom sort function :

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, { 
    "data-rank-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        a = (a==='') ? 99 : a; b = (b==='') ? 99 : b;    
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "data-rank-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        a = (a==='') ? -1 : a; b = (b==='') ? -1 : b;    
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});
```

And now it works! Blanks always appears at the end, both ascending and descending, and also if you enter new values to the input fields.

forked fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/s29aB/

To clarify the custom sort : I simply just set blanks / "" - values to be -1 on sorting ascending, 99 when sorting descending.

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked the fact that sType and sSortDataType could both be used and the map was throughing me off.